# How do i center objects in a movie clip relative to the center of the screen in order

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript

My problem is that i have a few movie clip instances in random places inside my `parent` movie clip, I want to be able to bring each of these movie clips in the `parent` to the center of the stage in a certain order by moving the parent movie clip.

The problem I am facing with this is that once i move the `parent` movie clip to center the 1st child on stage,  how do i move on to centering the next child on stage by moving the `parent`?

I want to be able to do this through actionscript.

Hopefully my problem is clear.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is extremely convoluted to the point of incoherence. Simplify...

Answer (score 0):

When placing your movieclips randomly, register in an array their positions, and move the parent calculating the differences between their coordinates

Answer (score 0):

if i was you i would center the parent on the stage, and then iterate through the children withing the parent, and center each one within the parent. then you would have both the parent and the children centers on the stage. you don't need to keep track of positions at all with this approach.